# How to get full command from doskey alias in Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, doskey

I'm using Windows PowerShell and it is configured using doskey macros.
I have a file named `Macros.doskey`.

```
105=code E:\static5\105
135=code E:\static5\135
static5=code E:\static5
```

How can I get the command corresponding to alias name ?

For example, when I type `105` in PowerShell it will execute the command `code E:\static5\105`

Now I want to know how to get the command from the alias name.

Comment: this `doskey /macros` will list out the current set of doskey macros. you can parse the resulting text fairly easily. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey that looks promising. How cool would it be if `Get-Command` and/or `Get-Alias` could be extended to list those?!

Comment: @briantist - i would not do it that way. i prefer to leave the builtin stuff unchanged. however, it is fairly easy to write a wrapper for those if desired. i would make a function that called `doskey` with a filter to match against a parameter value. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, `doskey /macros` command list out the complete set of doskey macros. How can I show only one command?

Comment: @SanjayRaz - use something like `doskey /macros | Where-Object {$_ -match $Var}` in a custom function. use the basic function template from the ISE to make it really easy. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **`doskey`** is a utility **primarily designed to work with `cmd.exe`, not PowerShell**.

  - PowerShell has better functionality built in, in the form of aliases and functions, and in Windows 10 you must even deactivate PowerShell's own command-line editing to even get `doskey` to work (see below).
- If you still want to use `doskey` in PowerShell, there are two **prerequisites**:

  - The [**`PSReadLine` module**](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) - which handles command-line editing since Windows 10 by default - must *not* be loaded, as it takes precedence over `doskey` definitions<sup>[1]</sup>; that is, you may need to **unload it explicitly with `Remove-Module PSReadLine`, but that means that you'll lose all of its benefits**.
  - You must invoke any `doskey.exe` macro definitions with `/exename=powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell) or `/exename=pwsh.exe` (PowerShell Core) for them to be usable from PowerShell.

    - Note that it is then `doskey` that expands a macro name typed by the user, which means that PowerShell only sees the *expanded* command and therefore has no knowledge of macro names. Therefore, trying to inspect `doskey` macros with 
      `Get-Command` won't work; inspect the output from `doskey /macros` instead, as in [Lee Dailey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55091437/45375).
    - Additionally, `doskey` also resolves macros when soliciting arbitrary user input via `Read-Host`<sup>[1]</sup>, which is undesired.

---

To summarize the **reasons for not using `doskey` in PowerShell**:

- It cannot be used with the `PSReadLine` module, which by default handles command-line editing since Windows 10 and provides invaluable functionality.
- `doskey` macro expansion invariably *also* occurs when scripts solicit arbitrary user input via `Read-Host`, which is undesired.

---

Therefore, I suggest you **abandon `doskey` in favor of PowerShell *functions*, and add them to your `$PROFILE` file** so that they're available in every session:

- While you *can* define functions named for numbers such as `105`in PowerShell, you'll have to invoke them with `&` so as to disambiguate from actual numbers, e.g., `& 105`.
- Therefore, I suggest refactoring your approach to **define a *single* function named, say, `c`**, that takes an optional *argument* to identify which file(s) to open:

```
function c { pushd E:/static5; code $(if ($Args) { $Args } else { '.' }); popd }
```

Your original `doskey` macros then map onto this function as follows:

- `105` -> `c 105`
- `135` -> `c 135`
- `static5` -> `c`

Note that this not only allows you to pass an arbitrary file name (of a file located in `E:/static5/`) to function `c`, but even *multiple* ones; e.g., `c 105 135` would open *both* files for editing.

To inspect the definition of function `c` later, you can simply call `$function:c` or, more verbosely, `(Get-Command c).Definition`.

---

<sup>[1] As [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) notes: "`doskey` performs translations on the console input buffer. [...]. It does not work if the console is not in line input mode, thus it is not compatible with `PSReadline`, although `Read-Host` will be affected.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpYzq.png"</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I've never used doskey with PowerShell, so I'm not sure how they appear. My best guess is that PowerShell sees them as commands of type "Application" which usually means external executables.

To start, check what PowerShell sees:

```
Get-Command 105 | Format-List *
# or
gcm 105 | fl *
```

From there, you might see just some exe like `doskey.exe` or maybe you'll see additional info too.

If it's just listed as an executable then I'm not sure you'll be able to get the info out of doskey.

PowerShell has its own versions of aliases which would have let you do full discovery, but PowerShell aliases can't take parameters, they just alias one command to another.

You could simulate doskey functionality in PowerShell by writing functions instead:

```
function static5 {
    code.exe 'E:\static5'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Your solution works when I use functions to simulate doskey functionalities but in my case, PowerShell give me some error like this         


Get-Command : The term '105' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Command 105 | Format-List *

Comment: @SanjayRaz that's very interesting, I don't know how the command could work in PowerShell while not being discoverable through `Get-Command`. Unfortunately I can't really take the time right now to do a doskey setup and investigate, but maybe someone else will be able to take that on. If possible I recommend moving on from doskey.

Comment: `doskey` do translation of console input buffer. PowerShell never see original line. It does not work if console is not in line input mode, thus it is not compatible with `PSReadline`, although `Read-Host` will be affected. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpYzq.png

Comment: @briantist: PetSerAl's comment implies that you'll never be able to inspect `doskey` macros with `Get-Command`, because `doskey` macros, _if_ they're actually in effect (they won't be with `PSReadLine` loaded, except when you use `Read-Host`, which is where you _don't_ want them), get expanded _before_ PowerShell ever sees the _already expanded_ command.

Answer (score 1):

this will do the job fairly well. [*grin*] note that it just gives the text matching the macro. i did not test with multiline macros, nor do i know if that is even possible.

if you want the result to be just the macro instead of the full line, you can add a `| ForEach-Object {$_.Split('=')[1]}` to get the part after the `=`.

```
@"
404=echo '404'
666=echo '666'
dwd=echo 'Doo Wa Diddy'
"@ | Set-Content "$env:TEMP\Doskey-Macros.txt" -Force

doskey /macrofile=c:\temp\doskey-macros.txt

function DKA ($Macro)
    {
    doskey /macros |
        Where-Object {
            $_ -match $Macro
            }
    }
```

testing & output ...

```
dka -Macro dwd
dwd=echo 'Doo Wa Diddy'

dka -Macro adg
# nothing at all since there was no match

dka 404
404=echo '404'
```