# `doskey /macros:all` produces quoted string I can't get rid of

Tags: powershell, windows-10, doskey

First, I'm in PowerShell and I've entered the `doskey /exename=powershell.exe` option.

Second, I did something that I now realize doesn't quite work:

```
doskey envpath=$env:Path -split ';'
```

The goal was to have it print the path environment variable (whatever it is at the time I later enter `envpath`).  However, it seems to have evaluated `$env:Path` while defining the macro, so the macro now appears to be all the paths in my path environment variable followed by '-split ;'.  So that's a problem, but only listed here for context. I'll figure that out separately.  The purpose of this question (one question per post) is the following:

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21464847/4516124) and getting something weird...

If I now enter `doskey /macros:all` I get:

```
    "envpath=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;<etc>;" -split ;
```

Please note the quotes.

Now, if, per the above-linked other answer, I enter `doskey envpath=something` (literally) then `doskey /macros:all` returns:

```
    "envpath=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;<etc>;" -split ;
    envpath=something
```

(which is expected except for the quoted part).

And when I do `doskey envpath=` it clears/deletes that macro, and `doskey /macros:all`, returns the first result again.

So my question: What is this entry in the quotes and how do I get rid of that please?

Hopefully I've explained that clearly enough. If confused please feel free to ask for clarification.  Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: there's no reason to use doskey when PowerShell already has the excellent PSReadLine (counter part of the wonderful bash [readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Readline-Interaction.html)). PowerShell also has profiles, functions, aliases similar to bash so it can do everything `doskey` can and far more

Comment: @phuclv So before now, I'd never heard of PSReadLine. I guess I should look into that. Might take some time, while a quick and dirty solution for now will suffice. But noted to look into it.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @DavidT, both the answer here and the one to your follow-up question advise against using `doskey.exe` in PowerShell, and provide a brief rationale as well as links to detailed information. The answer here shows how to make `doskey.exe` work nonetheless, if you so choose - at the expense of losing much of PowerShell's own, rich command-line editing experience, provided by the `PSReadLine` module, which is incompatible with `doskey.exe`. The linked answer shows you the arguably preferable PowerShell-idiomatic alternative to `doskey.exe`. Do you have any further questions?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the [answer to your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72763999/45375),

- **it's best to *avoid* use of [`doskey.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey) in PowerShell**, because getting it to work requires forgoing PowerShell's own, rich command-line editing experience, by unloading the [`PSReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/?view=powershell-7.2) module first (`Remove-Module PSReadLine`) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55094226/45375) for background information.
- the **better alternative is to define a *PowerShell function* and add it to your `$PROFILE` file**, as shown in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72763999/45375).

---

**If you want to use `doskey.exe` nonetheless**, define your macro as follows (for *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, replace `powershell.exe` with `pwsh.exe`):

```
doskey /exename=powershell.exe envpath = `$env:Path -split "';'"
```

- **The tokens that make up the PowerShell command must be passed as *individual arguments*** to `doskey.exe`, and be sure to **follow the `=` with a space**.

  - If you accidentally pass the PowerShell command as a *single*, quoted argument, `doskey.exe` stores enclosing `"..."` as part of the macro and includes these quotes when it expands the macro.
  - If you additionally also include the macro *name* in that single, quoted argument, you not only get a virtually unusable macro,<sup>[1]</sup> you also cannot *remove* it in-session (neither individually, with `doskey /exename=powershell.exe envpath=`, nor as part of clearing *all* macros with <kbd>Alt-F10</kbd>) - you must start a new PowerShell session to get rid of it.

    - Note that the macro name is also included if you attempt *partial* quoting in PowerShell, e.g.,  `` doskey envpath="`$env:Path -split ','" `` is effectively the same as `` doskey "envpath=`$env:Path -split ','" ``, due to how PowerShell rebuilds the command line behind the scenes (see below).
- To avoid *instant* expansion of `$env:Path`, the `$` character is preceded by PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters), the so-called backtick (`` ` ``).
- To preserve the `'...'`-quoting around `;`, outer `"..."` quoting is used.

  - This is necessary, because PowerShell *rebuilds* the command line behind the scenes when it invokes external programs, which involves translating `'...'` quoting into `"..."` quoting *if necessary*; that is, irrespective of what quoting was originally used on the PowerShell side, an argument is enclosed in `"..."` *if it contains spaces* and used *unquoted* otherwise; thus, `';'` by itself would turn into just `;` on the behind-the-scenes command line; an originally *partially* quoted argument that contains spaces ends up being double-quoted *as a whole*.

---

<sup>[1] In a macro definition that `doskey /macros` or `doskey /macros:all` lists as `"envpath=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;<etc>;" -split ;`, the macro name is `"envpath` *verbatim*, i.e. *including the opening `"`*. The - then unbalanced - *closing* `"` is retained in the text to expanded to.</sup>

Comment: Very helpful.  Thanks.  I'll try that shortly, but also want to add, do you have any idea what that quoted string returned by `doskey /macros:all` is and how to get rid of it?

Comment: @DavidT, it is implied by my update, but to spell it out: `doskey` macro definitions aren't _persistent_, so simply launching a new shell session wipes the slate clean. To make definitions persistent in PowerShell, you'd have to add `doskey` call(s) to the `$PROFILE` file; in `cmd.exe` you'd use the registry, as described in this [SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/1134468/139307).