# doskey to print `$env:Path -split ';'` (in PowerShell), except that doesn't work

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, doskey

Entering `$env:path` at the prompt correctly returns:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;...
```

Entering `$env:Path -split ';'` at the prompt correctly returns:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps                                   
...
```

Entering `doskey envpath=$env:Path -split ';'` at the prompt causes some pretty weird stuff that [I've asked elsewhere about cleaning up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72763275/doskey-macrosall-produces-quoted-string-i-cant-get-rid-of), but among other things appears to evaluate `$env:Path` at the time I'm *defining* the macro.

However the desired result is for it to evaluate `$env:Path` later, at the time I'm *running* the macro. How do I create a macro to do that?

Answer (score 0):

- **Don't try to use [`doskey.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey) in PowerShell**: To get it to work at all, you'd have to unload the module that handles interactive command-line editing in PowerShell, [`PSReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/?view=powershell-7.2) - which would take away a lot of useful features. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55094226/45375) for background information.
- Instead:

  - Define the desired functionality as a [`function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions).
  - Add that function to your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), so that it is available by default in future PowerShell sessions.

The following demonstrates this technique:

```
# Make sure the $PROFILE file exists.
if (-not (Test-Path $PROFILE)) {
  $null = New-Item -Force $PROFILE
}

# Add the desired functionality as a function definition.
@'

function envpath { $env:Path -split ';' }
'@ | Add-Content $PROFILE
```

<sup>Note the use of a (verbatim) [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@'<newline>...<newline>'@`), which makes embedding a function definition in a string syntactically easier, since no escaping of embedded quote characters is needed.</sup>

`envpath` will then be defined in future PowerShell sessions (unless the session was created with the CLI's `-NoProfile` switch).